# Can't select a column from csv file

Tags: sql, csv, perl, odbc, dbi

I use Perl to connect to a DBD::CSV with DBI, the connection works well and when I launch

```
SELECT * FROM dp_id.csv
```

It works fine but when I want to extract a single column.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect ("dbi:CSV:", undef, undef, { f_dir => "." });

my $query = " SELECT DpName from dp_id.csv";


my $sth   = $dbh->prepare ($query);
$sth->execute ();

while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array)
{
    print @row,"\n";
}
```

I've this error

```
 Execution ERROR: No such column 'dpname' called from extract.pl at 20.
 [for Statement " SELECT DpName from dp_id.csv"] at extract.pl line 20.
 DBD::CSV::st fetchrow_array failed: Attempt to fetch row without a preceding execute () call or from 
 a non-SELECT statement [for Statement " SELECT DpName from dp_id.csv"] at extract.pl line 22.
```

Here is an extract from the csv file:

```
kindOfInfo;DpName;TypeName;ID
interface;ALLARM;DPT_TS;344108
interface;POMP1;DPT_TS;7923082
```

Comment: @vkk05 in line 20 there is the execution of the query `$sth->execute()`

Comment: there is a space b/w `execute` and `()`. Is that causing the issue?

Comment: Provide a sample dp_id.csv file (Just a few lines worth).

Comment: What does the first line of your CSV file contain?

Comment: @vkk05: You can see that `execute()` is being called successfully. So, no, that space is not a problem.

Comment: @DaveCross I edit my question puting few lines in from my csv file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, DBD::CSV assumes that your files are comma separated (because that's what the "CS" in CSV stands for :-))

Your data is separated by semicolons. So you need to tell DBD::CSV that when creating the connection.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect ("dbi:CSV:", undef, undef, {
  f_dir        => ".",
  csv_sep_char => ';', # This is the important line
});
```

Without that, the DBD sees your data as single column with the name "kindOfInfo;DpName;TypeName;ID".